# Random integer in MATLAB

Tags: string, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I need to generate an input signal with a random digital message consisting of 40320 integers from 0 to 15 using the rectangular 16QAM modulation scheme for a minimum of 101 number of errors in order to determine the bit error rate.

How do I implement this in Matlab? I have written this code so far. Can anyone enlighten me please?

```
 M=16; %signal constellation size
 log2M =log2(M); %number of bits per symbol
 N= 40320; %No of random integers sent
 coderate =1;% FEC not required
 MinNoErr =101; %Minimum no of received symbol error 
 MaxNoErr =11e9; %Maximum no of received symbol error 
 nsamp =1; %No of samples per symbol
 B= randi([1, M-1],N,1); % Random integer data stream

% Modulate
hMod = comm.RectangularQAMModulator(M); % Create a 16-QAM modulator
txqam = modulate(modem.qammod(M),B);% Modulate using 16-QAM.
txqam =T; %transmited signal

% Send signal over an AWGN channel
EbNo = [5:1:15]; % In dB
SNR = EbNo + 10*log10(log2M*coderate) - 10*log10(nsamp);
hChan = comm.AWGNChannel('NoiseMethod', 'Signal to noise ratio (SNR)', ...
'SNR',SNR);

hChan.SignalPower = (T' * T)/ length(T);
ynoisy = step(hChan,T);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, all you need is a vector of length 40320 with random integers from the interval [1, 15]. If so, all you need is:

```
my_vector = randi(15 + 1, [1, 40320]) - 1;
```

Do clarify what it is that you need in case this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the response, however i am trying to implement 16QAM gray code arrangement such that the simulation run until 101 bit error occurs to enable me calculate BER(bit error rate) for various Eb/No values